# Tikz: Create depth effect with circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw circles to create a 3D effect. I'm having trouble figuring out how to rotate the image. Here is the code:

```
`\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\distin}{0.3}
\newcommand{\opacity}{0.3}

\newcommand{\xShift}{1.1}
\newcommand{\yShift}{1.1}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \foreach \i in {0,...,10}{
            \foreach \j in {0,...,7}{
                \draw [fill=black, opacity=\opacity, draw=black]
                (\distin*\i,\distin*\j) circle (1mm);
            }
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

At the moment the code generates the following image:

[image]

But I would like to have something like that:

[image]

How can I do that?
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this ?

[image: capture]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\distin}{0.2}
\newcommand{\opacity}{1}

\newcommand{\xShift}{1.1}
\newcommand{\yShift}{1.1}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

        \foreach \i [count=\c]in {10,...,0}{
            \foreach \j [evaluate =\j as \decrement using \j-\c*.5] in {7,...,0}{
                \draw [fill=blue!50,draw=blue, opacity=\opacity, draw=black]
                (\distin*.4*\i,\distin*\decrement) circle (1mm);
            }
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`tikz-3dplot` allows you to draw things in 3D and to adjust the view. You may change the view by adjusting `\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\distin}{0.3}
\newcommand{\opacity}{0.3}

\newcommand{\xShift}{1.1}
\newcommand{\yShift}{1.1}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}        
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
        \foreach \i in {10,9,...,0}{
            \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=\distin*\i]
            \foreach \j in {0,...,7}{
                \draw [fill=black, opacity=\opacity, draw=black]
                (0,\distin*\j) circle (1mm);
            }
            \end{scope}
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have circles that are not projected on the respective plane, use `dplot_screen_coords` instead of the corresponding plane.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\distin}{0.3}
\newcommand{\opacity}{0.3}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}        
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3]
        \foreach \i in {10,9,...,0}{
            \foreach \j in {0,...,7}{
                \draw [fill=black, opacity=\opacity, draw=black]
                (0,\distin*\i,\distin*\j) [tdplot_screen_coords] circle (1mm);
            }
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The meaning of the view angles is illustrated a bit by the following animation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\distin}{0.3}
\newcommand{\opacity}{0.3}
\foreach \X in {-70,-65,...,70}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{70+15*sin(\X)}{\X}        
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-4,-0.5) rectangle (4,4);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \foreach \i in {10,9,...,0}{
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=\distin*\i]
        \foreach \j in {0,...,7}{
            \draw [fill=black, opacity=\opacity, draw=black]
            (0,\distin*\j) circle (1mm);
        }
        \end{scope}
    }
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]